# How to understand this statement?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. For each element $g\in G$, $p_g$ is the map $G\rightarrow G$ defined by $p_g(x)= gx$ for all $x\in G$

**Prove, that $p_n$ is a permutation of $G$ (regarded as a set).**

Does that mean I have to put in $G$ (a whole set) for $x$? As far as I know, a permutation is performed ON a set and we put in elements of the set for $x$.

Or maybe it means $p_g(x)= Gx=\{g_1x,g_2x,g_3x,...,g_nx\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a **Permutation of $G$** ;we mean a bijective mapping from $G\to G$ .

Now $p_G(x_1)=p_G(x_2)\implies gx_1=gx_2\implies x_1=x_2\implies $injective

Corresponding to $x\in G$ we have $g^{-1}x\in G$ such that $p_G(g^{-1}x)=g(g^{-1}x)=x\implies$surjective .